# Subspace $\ell^2$ of square-summable sequences

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I check that a vector $x=(1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8,...)$ is in the subspace $\ell^2$ ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You just need to show that the sum $1^2+(1/2)^2+...+(1/2n)^2+...$ is convergent.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: Haven't you seen the sum of progressions $1+r+r^2+..+r^n+..$ where $r$ is the common ratio?

Comment: yes where that equals 1/(1-r) if -1<r<1

Comment: Good. Can you see what $r$ is in your sum?

Comment: I don't see an r.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that $\sum (1/2)^{2n}$ converges.  There are many tactics for doing this.  It is a geometric series, with r = $1/2^2$ = 1/4, so convergent.  Or you can compare it to a known convergent series: $0 < \sum (1/2)^{2n} <  \sum 1/2^n$ which is known to converge.